# Assertive programming with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, assert, assertion

I am looking for a way to do assertive programming on pandas dataframes data as does [`assertr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertr/vignettes/assertr.html) in R.

Are there any convenient library for that ?
All Advice are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question: [engarde](https://engarde.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of analogous libraries that integrate specifically with Pandas, but [`assert`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_assert.asp) is a built-in keyword in Python, which you could use to validate data at various points in your data pipeline.

The syntax is simply:

```
assert [condition]
```

If true, nothing happens. If false, an [`AssertionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError) is raised.

To validate Pandas data you could write a statement like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# throws an exception if there are negative values in the sepal_length column
assert (iris['sepal_length'] > 0).all()
```

Comment: I was looking for a something more integrated to pandas.